# Maven performance in Java applications

Tags: java, maven

I can see the advantages of using Maven in any enterprise application. However, my question is: can the use of Maven increase or decrease the performance of a Java application at all?

Comment: Are you sure you really understand what Maven does ? You would not ask this if you knew exactly what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven doesn't affect runtime performance.

Maven is used primarily at development time for build management, testing and deployment. It doesn't really have a role at application runtime (except in some unusual situations, e.g. if Maven is being used by the application to dynamically download plugins).

Answer (score 1):

Maven is a build and dependency management tool and therefore has nothing to do with the performance of your application. 
It may have an impact on your build time, but the performance of the code lies more in the code itself than in the build.

Answer (score 1):

Maven is a dependency and build management framework.

It has NOTHING to do with your application , except fetch all the dependencies and build the app to your desired packaging format (jar/war/ear)

This is one time job and happens in BUILD phase,

Applciation PERFORMANCE is related to Execution Phase, where Maven doesn't have anything to do.

Answer (score 0):

Come to deployment time no. Maven is all about development and build time. Once you are ready to deploy, it should just be a standard deployment as could be built by ant, ivy or anything else.

Some people complain about it's build performance and prescriptive nature (convention over configuration). But it has wide support and adoption (as evidenced by the wide availability of repositories and builds).

Maven works by downloading missing dependencies to a local repository. Using a repository in your company can make this process significantly quicker for teams.